# How do I go about two factor authentication using requests library?

Tags: python, two-factor-authentication

I have a post and a get request to a website that uses 2FA (DUO mobile). When I execute the code, I get a push notification on my phone asking me to accept or reject the request for a login. I don't know what to do after I've done this much. I know how 2FA works but I'm new to requests and stuff.

````
    url = "https://www.something.edu/apps/account/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Frf.something.something.edu"
    r = session.get(url, headers = headers)


    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
    login_data['lt'] = soup.find('input', attrs={'name' : 'lt' })['value']
    r = session.post(url, data = login_data, headers = headers, )
    print(r.content)```

It does not print anything and the program keeps running
````

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is asking. Once you send the POST it presumably pings your phone for the 2FA, so now what? The POST response probably gives you some token back that can be used in future requests to indicate identity, I'd guess? Without a lot more understanding of the system, though, it's tough to advise you.

Comment: I found the issue with the above problem. I had to set allow_redirects=False when making the post request. Apparently, the program got stuck in an infinite loop trying to redirect. I am now facing a CAS ticket validation error but I think that problem for another thread. Thanks for trying to help though...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting allow_redirects=False while making the post request. Apparently, the post request got stuck in an infinite loop of redirects. The post request now would be

`r = session.post(url, data = login_data, headers = headers, allow_redirects=False)`